# STR/LDR to memory in ARMSim#

Tags: assembly, arm

I have an introductory assignment to make a small program using ARMSim# (10 lines, maximum) just to get used to basic commands.

So I tried to make this:

```
MOV r1, #4
MOV r2, #15
STR r2, [r1]
LDR r3, [r1]
SWI 0x11
```

This program is supposed to assign the direct value "4" into r1 register, than assign the direct value "15" to r2 register. After that, it should store r2 content in "address 4" of my memory (I know the memory addresses must be multiples of 4) and finally, r3 should get the content from "address 4" memory, but all it gets is 0.

What's wrong with it? I tried looking in other sites, but their syntax are the same as mine, but I still can't manage to put r2 content into r3 using `LDR` and `STR`. I know I could use `MOV` to do that, but my intention is to learn some new instructions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ARMSim, but typically the ARM reset vector (i.e. where code starts executing from) is address 0, which would mean address 4 is your `mov r2, #15` instruction. If it simulates code areas as ROM then you're not going to be able to overwrite that, or it may just be otherwise weird about data access to code - best check the memory map to find out where actual RAM lives.

Comment: Ah no, seems things are even simpler than that (as an instruction set simulator, it doesn't even go into such architectural detail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm testing with ARMSim# Version 1.9.1 (20500).

In the MemoryView, the value for address 0x00000004 was ???????? and one for address 0x00002004 was 81818181. From this, i think that address 0x00000004 is not writable in ARMSim#

I set the address to 0x00002004 and it worked.

```
MOV r1, #0x800
ADD r1, r1, r1
ADD r1, r1, r1
MOV r2, #4
ADD r1, r1, r2

MOV r2, #15

STR r2,[r1]

LDR r3, [r1]

SWI 0x11
```

Comment: It really worked, but I have another question: to know which address is writable? I suppose I need to go through MemoryView and find the first address which do not contain ?????????, right? And use the memory address to set my register up?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `Starting Address of Main Memory` in `Main Memory` tab in `Files > Preferences` seems working in ARMSim# Version 1.9.1 (20500), but I'm not sure if this is a safe way because data in the location wasn't `81818181`, which is used for filling memory.

Answer (score 0):

ARMSim#'s default memory map seems to have RAM starting at 0x1000, with the code placed at the start, and the total amount of memory being the sum of the code size (rounded up to the next KB) plus the semihosting heap and stack size. Therefore, assuming the default configuration you've got 65k of RAM from 0x1000 to 0x11400. Addresses outside that range are not memory, so won't work as expected (seems they simply read as zero and ignore writes, rather than raising any kind of error), however even within that range you still need to be careful about stomping on your own instructions.

Rather than using hardcoded addresses, it would be better to specifically allocate space for variables in your code (using `.word` and friends), then you can refer to the symbols and let the assembler worry about getting the actual addresses right - that way you also get a good excuse to learn about `adr` (and/or the `ldr=` pseudo-op) and the literal form of `ldr`/`str`. Or for really temporary storage, use the stack; the SP register starts out already initialised to an appropriate value.